# Can't choose apple certificate when creating a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I am confused now for that I can't choose the certificate I created for APNs app when I want to create a provisioning profile.Here are some screenshots.Does anyone know the reason?

oh,my god! I have no enough reputation to post images...

Who has had encountered a similar problem?
Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: I can post images on some third-party site and add a link here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from looking to your certificate in your key chain and if they are there and on dev center too then create the application bundle id and provisioning profile too, else if you not have anything or missing look into a good tutorial steps to create your certificate and provisioning profile

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have found that if there is only a APNs certification, I can't choose it when create the provisioning profile.However, I can create a common certification and then I can choose the common certification when create my provisioning profile, and also, by using this provisioning profile and common certification, I can  work with my APNs demo app normally.

Comment: Yes, APN certificate needed with bundle id but for creating provisioning certificate you need your normal keychain certificate

Comment: I am a little confused, doesn't it need a APNs development type certification when I develop my app which has APNs function?

Comment: It does, but not for creating the provisioning profile but for creating you .pem file or .p12 so that you can send your push from your server to apple server